# How do I re-use the same default arguments in an R-package? And how do I pass them on to nested functions?

Tags: r, package

I'm writing an R-package, in which I want to enable some unit-conversion like operations. However, the parameters that are required for the conversion (e.g. 273.15 for degrees Celsius to Kelvin conversion) are subject to change (some were re-calibrated in 2010!). This means that I want to pass them as function arguments so that the user may easily change them, but since they are used in several functions, I'd like to figure out a way to do this "globally".

However, global parameters are evil, and I want my functions to remain fully functional (always give the same output given the same input).

- I want to document where the default values come from (references)
- I only want to define the values once, so that I can easily update them
- I want to pass these values to several functions as default values
- I want to pass the values as defaults to functions, that have nested functions that also require the parameters. Preferably the parameters keep the same name.

So an example:

```
# example data to work with
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(x = 1:10, input = rnorm())

# first function, documented in roxygen2 style

#' Apply correction
#'
#' @importFrom magrittr `%>%`
#' @param dat Data to process.
#' @param input the column quosure of dat to apply the correction to.
#' @param factora Correction factor A to apply. Defaults to 0.3545, from \citet{Anon2018}.
#' @param factorb Correction factor B to apply. Defaults to 8.988, from \citet{Bnon2018}.
apply_correction <- function(dat, input = quo(input), factora = 0.3545, factorb = 8.988) {
  dat %>%
      mutate(processed = !!input * factora - factorb)
}

#' Multiple steps
#'
#' @inheritParams apply_correction
#' @inheritParams function_that_uses_factorc
multiple_steps <- function(dat, factorc = 3.421, factora = 0.3545, factorb = 8.988) {
        dat %>%
           mutate(step1 = input * factorc) %>%
           apply_correction(quo(step1), factora = factora, factorb = factorb)
}
```

I've considered creating an environment in which I specify all defaults, then get them from the environment as default values. But I'm not too sure this is good practise for a package. Please help :).

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function that takes no arguments and returns a vector/list of your stored values. Then you just pass that function call as an argument to whichever function needs those values.

apply_correction(dat, input, factors=default_factors())

Have your function return a named list or vector, so you can access the data in a sensible way: factors$a